# Why `\connect mydb` prevents error `function unaccent(text) does not exists`?

Tags: postgresql, database-restore

I restored my database successfully on one cluster, but when I try to do same on different cluster with same custom PostgreSQL database image I got errors:

```
ERROR:  function unaccent(text) does not exist
LINE 2:   SELECT unaccent(coalesce($1, ''));
                 ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:
  SELECT unaccent(coalesce($1, ''));

CONTEXT:  SQL function "str_norm" during inlining
ERROR:  relation "banners_text_search" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT text from banners_text_search
                         ^
QUERY:  SELECT text from banners_text_search
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW
ERROR:  function unaccent(text) does not exist
LINE 2:   SELECT unaccent(coalesce($1, ''));
                 ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:
  SELECT unaccent(coalesce($1, ''));

CONTEXT:  SQL function "str_norm" during inlining
```

When I connected to restored database I can find `unaccent` function and `banners_text_search` relation. This is expected, because I did not encounter any errors when they were created. So problem is only with `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW`.

I supposed that this instance is too fast, so I added `\connect mydb` just before `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` statements:

```
docker exec old-postgres-node bash -c "pg_dumpall --clean --if-exists -U postgres             | \
egrep -v '^(CREATE|DROP) ROLE( IF EXISTS)? postgres;'                                         | \
sed '/^DROP ROLE.*datadog/ i REVOKE ALL ON TABLE pg_catalog.pg_stat_database FROM datadog;'   | \
sed '/connect userdb/ r create-extensions.sql'                                                | \
sed '/^REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW public.banners_text_search;/ i \\\\\\connect mydb'           | \
psql -h 172.17.42.1 -p 5433 -U postgres -d postgres; "
```

Now everything goes smooth:

```
...
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
GRANT
You are now connected to database "userdb" as user "postgres".
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW
```

Does anybody know what was the actual problem with `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` without reconnection to the database`\connect mydb`?

Comment: Could be the search path, could be create-extensions.sql or something else. But unaccent() is clearly not available within the scope of your database connection.

Comment: @FrankHeikens: `unnacent` come from `CREATE EXTENSION` statement in the beginning of the script. Also `CREATE FUNCTION`, `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW` done without any errors: https://pastebin.com/t5eHtj4k Because of that I am curious: why only `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` issue errors and `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW` is unaffected.

Comment: Aren't you replacing `connect userdb` two lines above? Where you load your extensions.

Comment: This report is unclear. How exactly did you restore the database? Were there any errors during the restore? What are the exact versions involved? What statements exactly did you run to get the errors in the beginning of your question? What is the business with `\connect mydb`? To which database were you connected before that? Different databases have different objects.